# Ionic2 SqlStorage problema in device couldn't find "libsqlc-native-driver.so"

Tags: android, ionic2

I have implemented SqlStorage in my ionic2 app, and it was working fine. I added yesterday a column to a table, so I made a drop table first, and the table create then, but when I deployed the app to the device, I see the following errors in the ddms.

```
11-14 17:47:33.332: E/chromium(32126): [ERROR:layer_tree_host_impl.cc(2206)] Forcing zero-copy tile initialization as worker context is missing
11-14 17:47:35.954: E/chromium(32126): [ERROR:xwalk_autofill_client.cc(121)] Not implemented reached in virtual void xwalk::XWalkAutofillClient::OnFirstUserGestureObserved()
11-14 17:47:36.064: E/chromium(32126): [ERROR:xwalk_autofill_client.cc(121)] Not implemented reached in virtual void xwalk::XWalkAutofillClient::OnFirstUserGestureObserved()
11-14 17:47:36.555: E/AndroidRuntime(32126): FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-2-thread-1
11-14 17:47:36.555: E/AndroidRuntime(32126): Process: com.ionicframework.coopiapp955107, PID: 32126
11-14 17:47:36.555: E/AndroidRuntime(32126): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ionicframework.coopiapp955107-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ionicframework.coopiapp955107-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libsqlc-native-driver.so"
11-14 17:47:36.555: E/AndroidRuntime(32126):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
11-14 17:47:36.555: E/AndroidRuntime(32126):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
11-14 17:47:36.555: E/AndroidRuntime(32126):    at io.liteglue.SQLiteConnector.<init>(SQLiteConnector.java:8)
11-14 17:47:36.555: E/AndroidRuntime(32126):    at io.sqlc.SQLiteConnectorDatabase.<clinit>(SQLiteConnectorDatabase.java:36)
11-14 17:47:36.555: E/AndroidRuntime(32126):    at io.sqlc.SQLitePlugin.openDatabase(SQLitePlugin.java:211)
11-14 17:47:36.555: E/AndroidRuntime(32126):    at io.sqlc.SQLitePlugin.access$000(SQLitePlugin.java:32)
11-14 17:47:36.555: E/AndroidRuntime(32126):    at io.sqlc.SQLitePlugin$DBRunner.run(SQLitePlugin.java:327)
11-14 17:47:36.555: E/AndroidRuntime(32126):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-14 17:47:36.555: E/AndroidRuntime(32126):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-14 17:47:36.555: E/AndroidRuntime(32126):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-14 17:47:38.807: E/chromium(32126): [ERROR:runtime_javascript_dialog_manager.cc(70)] Not implemented reached in virtual void xwalk::RuntimeJavaScriptDialogManager::ResetDialogState(content::WebContents*)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved uninstalling the cordova plugin and installing it again from the repository (justo to get the last version).

The steps I have followed are the following:

1) Open cmd in admin mode.

2) Go to the project root folder.

3) Execute the command cordova plugin list . This will list all the plugins installed. Pay atention to the sqlite-storage one, you will need the name in the following step.

4) Execute cordova plugin remove [pluginName] ("cordova-sqlite-storage" in my case)

5) Install again the plugin with the command: 
cordova plugin add https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage